# SQL - while joining if matching not found then use default value

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have table A like this.

```
id | eventtime
--------------
1 | 2020-05-01 10:00:12
2 | 2020-04-03 04:04:23
3 | 2020-06-01 00:01:00
```

Table B

```
qid|id | timestamp           | status
-------------------------------------
1  | 1 | 2020-04-03 01:00:00 | Y
2  | 1 | 2020-05-02 04:11:00 | N
3  | 2 | 2020-04-02 03:00:00 | Y
4  | 4 | 2020-06-01 01:00:00 | N
5  | 4 | 2020-06-03 01:00:00 | Y
```

I want to join these tables, but it should return the Table'B data when the timestamp is > the Table A's event time.

#### EG:

**From Table B,**

For id 1 I have 3 rows, But I need to pick the rows where the timestamp> tableA.eventtime

So `2  | 1 | 2020-05-02 04:11:00 | N`

For id 2,  the timestamp value is less than the tableA's event time, so skip this.

So the selected row is, `2  | 1 | 2020-05-02 04:11:00 | N`

For id 4, there is no eventtime, in fact, no rows for ID 4 on table A. So now I need to pass a default timestamp for this. That is `2020-06-02 00:00:00`

So the selected row is `5  | 4 | 2020-06-03 01:00:00 | Y`

### Expected output:

```
qid|id | timestamp           | status
-------------------------------------
2  | 1 | 2020-05-02 04:11:00 | N
5  | 4 | 2020-06-03 01:00:00 | Y
```

Im stuck while writing the logic for this? Could somebody help me?

Comment: Please update your question with the queries you have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
select b.*
from b left join
     a
     on a.id = b.id 
where b.timestamp > coalesce(a.eventtime, '2020-06-02 00:00:00'::timestamp);
```

Comment: Hey @gordon-linoff

just a thought, 
Instead of the OR operation if I give just `b.timestamp > coalesce(a.eventtime, '2020-06-02 00:00:00'::timestamp)` will it work?

Comment: @Bhuvanesh . . . Yes.  I'm not sure why I put the `or` in with the `coalesce()`.  Either can be done, but the `coalesce()` is simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CASE](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-case/) statements in your query.

```
SELECT B.*
  FROM B LEFT JOIN A ON A.ID = B.ID
 WHERE CASE
          WHEN B.TIMESTAMP >
                  CASE
                     WHEN A.EVENTTIME IS NULL
                     THEN
                        TO_DATE ('20200602', 'YYYYMMDD')
                     WHEN A.EVENTTIME IS NOT NULL
                     THEN
                        A.EVENTTIME
                  END
          THEN
             1
          ELSE
             0
       END = 1
```